# How to convert two ints (swings, hits) to accuracy

Tags: java, math

How would I convert swings and hits to accuracy? I know how to calculate the swing/hit ratio but I don't know how to convert it to accuracy.

This is what I've tried:

```
public double convertToMeleeAccuracy(int swings, int hits) {
        try {
            double classicHitAccuracy = Double.valueOf(swings - hits); //I know the math for getting the ratio is swings / hits but i don't know how to calculate accuracy.

            if (classicwlr < 0) {
                return 0.0;
            }

            return classicwlr;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The accuracy *is* that ratio.

Comment: swings = total, hits = count (<= total). So `((double) count) / totals` The cast to double is to prevent integer division like 7/3 = 2, i.o. 2.667

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to explain this to you in a way that helped me calculate percentages easily throughout my life.

Let's look at this like so:
Say swings is always 10, so in this scenario, each swing is worth 10% of the accuracy. (because the max accuracy will always be 100%) In that case the function will look something like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertToMeleeAccuracy(3)); // Can be any number you'd like under 10.
    }

    public static double convertToMeleeAccuracy(int hits) {
        int swings = 10;
        double percentage = 100.0 / swings;
        return hits * percentage;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, the program will output 30.0 which means 30% of the hits have hit.

---

In the scenario above I only used the number 10 because it's an easy number to work with, here's an example of how this would work with any number of swings:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertToMeleeAccuracy(22, 21)); // Can be any numbers you'd like.
    }

    public static double convertToMeleeAccuracy(int swings, int hits) {
        double percentage = 100.0 / swings;
        return hits * percentage;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, the function will output 95.45454545454547 which is the correct accuracy and you can use any numbers you'd like.

You can also add some checks in the function to make sure hits isn't higher than swings etc..

I hope I helped you understand!